# Как изменить свойства файла С++

Tags: c++, файлы

Нужно удалять файлы, в том числе и файлы "Только чтение".
Если в свойствах стоит галочка "Только чтение", то через remove() удалить не получается. Пытался получать информацию о файле в структуру _finddata_t и в ней менять поле attrib,

```
char[50] path; // Путь к файлу и маска поиска
_finddata_t file; 
_findfirst(path, &file);      
file.attrib = _A_NORMAL;// Попытка сделать файл без запретов на чтение или запись
```

но тоже ничего.Файл всё равно не удаляется и галочка не снимается. Хотя если снять галолчку в ручную(ПКМ по файлу->свойства), то только тогда удаляется.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идет о Windows, то тогда можно будет использовать функцию [`SetFileAttributesW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileattributesw)

Answer (score 2):

В POSIX определена такая функция - [`_chmod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1z319a54.aspx), так что, как по мне, самый переносимый способ удалить R/O файл - примерно

```
int killFile(const char * name)
{
    if (name==0) return 1;
    if (remove(name)) {
        _chmod(name,_S_IWRITE);
    } else return 0;
    return remove(name);
};
```

Т.е. если первая попытка удалить не проходит - снимаем R/O и пробуем еще раз...

P.S. То, что делаете вы - примерно то же самое, что, пересчитав деньги в кошельке, записать сумму на бумажке (снять информацию о файле в структуру `file`). После чего увеличить **на бумажке** (изменить поле структуры `file`) сумму в 10 раз и надеяться, что в кошельке от этого что-то прибавится...